# Start a second WiFi on laptop

Tags: wireless, network-manager

- I use standard Ubuntu 14.04 with `network-manager`.
- I am connected to a wifi with my second `wlan1` card.

How do I tell network-manager to let me configure my `wlan0` card on my own with `ifconfig`?

In the end I would like to adapt [this script](https://github.com/ffnord/batman-connect/blob/master/batman-connect), so It leaves the control of `wlan1` to network-manager

Comment: The simplest way I know of to get NM to ignore an interface is to mention it in `/etc/network/interfaces`. Since you'll be using ifconfig later anyway, that should be enough.

Comment: What do you mean my "mentioning"? can you give an example? (that would be an answer then, wouldn't it? ;) )

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are two ways I know of to get Network Manager to ignore a device:

#### Mention it in [`/etc/network/interfaces`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/en/man5/interfaces.5.html)

Any valid configuration will do. This depends on `managed` being set to `false` (or unset) in `/etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf`. From the [manpage](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/en/man5/NetworkManager.conf.5.html):

```
[ifupdown]
This section contains ifupdown-specific options and thus only has effect
when using ifupdown plugin.

managed=false | true
    Controls whether interfaces listed in the 'interfaces' file are 
    managed by NetworkManager.  If set to true, then interfaces listed 
    in /etc/network/interfaces are managed by NetworkManager.  
    If set to false, then any interface listed in /etc/network/interfaces 
    will be ignored by NetworkManager. Remember that NetworkManager 
    controls the default route, so because the interface is ignored, 
    NetworkManager may assign the default route to some other interface.  
    When the option is missing, false value is taken as default.
```

So, you can add to `/etc/network/interfaces` something like:

```
auto wlan0
iface wlan0 inet manual
```

#### Add it to the list of unmanaged devices

From the manpage:

```
[keyfile]
This section contains keyfile-specific options and thus only has effect
when using keyfile plugin.
...
unmanaged-devices=mac:<hwaddr>;mac:<hwaddr>;...
    Set devices that should be ignored by NetworkManager when using 
    the keyfile plugin. Devices are specified in the following format: 
    "mac:<hwaddr>", where <hwaddr> is MAC address of the device to be 
    ignored, in hex-digits-and-colons notation. Multiple entries are 
    separated by a semicolon. No spaces are allowed in the value.
    Example:
    unmanaged-devices=mac:00:22:68:1c:59:b1;mac:00:1E:65:30:D1:C4
```

First look up the MAC address:

```
ifconfig wlan0 | grep -i HWaddr
```

Here, you'd edit `/etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf`. Under a `[keyfile]` section (add one if it doesn't exist), add:

```
unmanaged-devices=mac:some-mac-address
```

---

The first method depends on the `ifupdown` plugin being used, and the second depends on the `keyfile` plugin being used. By default, both are used, and `managed` is `false`.

You need to restart Network Manager for changes to the configuration file to take effect (thanks, @rubo77):

```
sudo service network-manager restart
```

Comment: I use Ubuntu 14.04. I rebooted my laptop and now your first solution seems to work: nm-applet sais: "Gerät wird nicht verwaltet" (= something like "Device is not managed")

Comment: @rubo77 also note that whatever it is you plan to do, you maybe able to do it using [/etc/network/interfaces](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/en/man5/interfaces.5.html).